# Are JPA Ids sequential

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework, uniqueidentifier

Play framework creates an Id for Entities which extend the model class as such:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Model extends GenericModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public Object _key() {
        return getId();
    }

}
```

Is it possible to use this id (max id) to determine the latest created record?

I want to make some jobs rerunnable from a certain point in the event of failures and this would be by far the easiest way to add this functionality.

I do not want to add a creation time column as the table is already huge.

Comment: Followup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386189/configuring-play-1-x-jpa-to-generate-entity-ids-sequentially

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `strategy()` for `@GeneratedValue` is `GenerationType.AUTO`. The definition is

> Indicates that the persistence provider should pick an appropriate strategy for the particular database. The `AUTO` generation strategy may expect a database resource to exist, or it may attempt to create one. A vendor may provide documentation on how to create such resources in the event that it does not support schema generation or cannot create the schema resource at runtime.

So it depends on the database you use. If you use `GenerationType.IDENTITY`, some database vendors use some kind of "auto_increment" value. At least, this is true for MySQL. If you use MySQL with `GenerationType.IDENTITY` you can use `max(id)` to determine the latest created record. For further information, I'd check your database spec.